# FREE SHIPPING configuration not working for diffrent products in cart

Tags: magento2, product, free-shipping

Magento2 experts. I need a help. I need FREE SHIPPING on 3 or 3+ products. I set in cart price rule. in Action- "Quantity in cart equals or greater than 3" When I add same 3 products to the cart, it works. but, If I add separate 3 products in the cart, It doesn't work. How?

Answer (score 0):

The “quantity” is under the heading of “Cart Item Attribute”. This means it’s matching against each line item in the cart, not the cart overall.

I believe if you want to do this, you need to make it a condition, not an action. The condition would be “Total Items Quantity” under the “Cart Attributes” heading.

Conditions determine when the rule applies, actions determine which items the rule is applicable to. For example you could offer free shipping when buying 3 or more items, but restrict it so that the items would have to be in certain categories.